# Would this be a good substiute for javascript not having a static keyword?

Tags: javascript, static

```
function get_radio_value()
{
   for (var i=0; i < document.fm1.gp1.length; i++)
   {
      if (document.fm1.gp1[i].checked)
      {
         var rad_val = document.fm1.gp1[i].value;
         if(rad_val == "Last Name"){
            get_radio_value.url = "rpc.php";
         }

       }
    } 
 }
```

then outside the scope you can call

```
alert( get_radio_value.url);
```

basically all you need to do is call the function name dot variable like this get_radio_value.url insdead of using the static keyword. Would this be a good substiute for static?

Comment: If you mean a static method, a la most languages, you're not using it that way.  This is syntactic sugar at best.

Comment: @uncle brad: I think he means a static variable within a function, like in C or C++.

Comment: @casa - Thanks, you're right, even if this isn't a classic example (it doesn't demonstrate that url behaves like a static, only that it's accessed like one).  I've got to stop trying to answer questions on Friday, because what I've just said isn't correct.

Comment: "I've got to stop trying to answer questions on Friday, because what I've just said isn't correct."  Must... understand.. self-contradictory... sentence..... *BOOM*

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a reasonable approximation of static behaviour in, e.g. C/C++.  The variable is local to the function.

One difference is that you don't get to initialise the variable just once.
You could do:

```
  get_radio_value.url = get_radio_value.url || "initial value";
```

But if get_radio_value.url is assigned the undefined value, it will be reinitialised in the function, next time round, which is not have static normally works.